# Making extension to read a name of an audio file in an element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to make an extension, that reads a name of an audio file inside an audio tag. The tag looks like this : `<audio id=jp_audio_1 preload=metadata src=“mp3/1/example.mp3></audio>`
I’m unsure where to start with developing it… I hope for your help :)

Comment: Please define what "the name" means in that context. An audio source doesn't have a name.

Comment: Don’t files have names? What’s the “correct” name for it?

Comment: I want to read the name of the source file

Comment: It's a URL, not a file. It may be a file on the server side but you won't know its name, or its a DB row, nor does it matter, because at the end the only thing that matters is that the URL returns some blob of data of the right MIME type, no name required. It _may_ be that the final part of the URL looks like a usable name like in your example, but it may also not be. The URL can be `https://example.com/?id=18` or `data:audio/mp3;base64,gaidie6Jw9P...` or `blob:https://example.com/6f82e95d`. No filenames involved. Also, it could have been that you were trying to read the title from ID3 tags...